# Jquery Popup Message Showing before button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, bpopup

hi there I have [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/uRVaf/) but for some reason the message its showing before clicking on the buttons. I don't know why its happening. I am new to this, so I have been trying with different things but its not working properly. I also don't know how I can position it in different places .  the code suppose to be this

```
$('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
            follow: [false, false], //x, y
            position: [150, 400] //x, y
        });
```

but when I put it in there it doesnt work at all.

---

HTML:

```
<button id="my-button">POP IT UP</button>
<!-- Element to pop up -->
<div id="element_to_pop_up">
  <div id="popup" style="left: 424.5px; position: fixed; top: 133.5px; z-index: 9999; display: block;">
        <span class="button bClose"><span>X</span></span>
        If you can't get it up use<br>
        <span>bPopup</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#popup {

    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 5px #999;
    color: #111;
    display: none;
    min-width: 450px;
    padding: 25px;

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
#element_to_pop_up {display:none;}
```

Here is the fiddle

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/QTXZE/)

Comment: @Neal There is no css for this <div id="element_to_pop_up"> and this is where the problem is

Comment: Dude! Ummm what is this 'Dude' you speak of?

Comment: @VIDesignz do you knwo why this doesnt work   $('#my-button').on('click', function(e) {

                // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
                e.preventDefault();

                // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
                 $('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
            follow: [false, false], //x, y
            position: [150, 400] //x, y
        });

            });

Comment: '                  $('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
            follow: [false, false], //x, y
            position: [150, 400] //x, y
        });

            });'

Comment: @behzad check out the fiddle again, I updated it so the positioning works

Comment: @VIDesignz Thank you very much sir, I have one more question, is there anyway to add animation when you click on close, like fade it in a different way?

Comment: @behazad Your welcome..That depends on what the plugin offers, I would suggest looking into it more, or even modifying the plugin script itself.

Comment: Thank you , i will try to look into it more

Comment: Y'know, if y'all put more effort into explaining the problems with the code *in your answers* rather than expecting folks to diff disparate fiddles, you wouldn't encounter so much confusion.

Comment: @Shog9 Agreed...guilty as charged

Comment: @behzad_b: mentioning [the plugin you were using](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/) would help.

Comment: OH okay, @Shog9 then I apologize from everyone, i am learning, now I know for next time.

Answer (score 3):

Ummm you have `display: block;` in the inline css:

```
<div id="popup" 
 style="left: 424.5px; position: fixed; top: 133.5px; z-index: 9999; display: block;">
```

This overrides the style in your stylesheet, giving you a bad time. You want to just remove it:

```
<div id="popup" 
 style="left: 424.5px; position: fixed; top: 133.5px; z-index: 9999;">
```

---

#### To explain:

You have `display: block;` inside of the css that is on your popup's `style` attribute.

You need to **remove** that, and then your `display: none` in your real CSS will kick in where it is supposed to.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uRVaf/4/

Comment: @robjb Here is the original example with the only the change Neal suggested http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/uRVaf/5/ and guess what...the whole script breaks. If you, or Neal, want to leave it at that and consider it solved, then go for it.  Most on this site would go a step further and help make it work...

Comment: @VIDesignz The only reason why that breaks is because there are script tags where they don't belong. Look at the example in my answer, and you see that it works.

Comment: @Neal The OP had the .bpopup attached to #element_to_pop_up, you changed that, and sure, the popup itself comes up with that change, but with that change, the screen doesnt show, nor can you close it. As to why you would downvote my answer when it actually works as intended is beyond me. I guess all those reputation points have gone to your head...

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like `onclick` or `onsubmit` ;

```
<input type="button" name="button" value = "submit" onclick="POPup()"  />
```

and your javaScript code would b like

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function POPup(){
//.... your pop up code goes here
}
</script>
```